# Partitioning vectors from Z^k into bundles preserving their additive properties

Tags: additive-combinatorics, integer-sequences, integer-programming

Let $B_1, B_2, \dots, B_m$ be disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^k$ and $B$ denote their union.
Also suppose that $k$ upper bounds the $\ell^\infty$-norm of every vector in $B$.
A set $V \subseteq B$ of size $m$ is called well-partitioned if $|V \cap B_i| = 1$ for each $i \in 1, \dots, m$.
Let us say that $B_1, B_2, \dots, B_m$ is a $(c,k,m)$-partitioning sequence if

1. Each set $B_i$ has $c$ elements, $m$ is the sequence length, and $k$ has meaning as above.
2. If $V_1,V_2 \subseteq B$ are both of size $m$ and sum up to the same vector then either both are well-partitioned or none of them.

I wonder if it is possible to construct a $(3,k,m)$-partitioning sequence with $m$ being exponentially large in terms of $k$. The difficulty comes from the fact that the number of possible vector sums is way smaller than the number of size-$m$ subsets of $B$.

I am aware that the question is very specific but I would be happy to learn about any construction that might seem related.